# Do not submit the for using beforeSubmit function

Tags: jqgrid

I have a `beforeSubmit` function in edit options. Code of the function is like below

```js
beforeSubmit: function (postdata, formid) {
    var myGrid = $('#list'),
    selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
    IsIssued = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Status');
    alert(IsIssued);
    if (IsIssued == true)
        return [false,"lll"];
    else
        return [true,"ll"];
}
```

But the problem is that this always submits the form. What I want is that,
 `if (IsIssued==true)` then do not submit the Form return an error.
else 
submit the form.
I am getting the exact value of `IsIssued` successfully.

Comment: It seems me very strange that you use `getCell` to verify whether the form could be submitted or not. The value is known **before** starting of editing. Why the user should can edit such row, but then don't allow to submit the changes? Probably you should deny editing of such rows or you should get **new** value of `Status` from `postdata` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the afterShowForm function and made the EditForm hidden

```
afterShowForm: function ()
{
var myGrid = $('#list'),
selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
IsIssued = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Status');
if (IsIssued == 'true') {

$.jgrid.hideModal("#editmodlist");
alert("This Book Is Already Issued");
return [true];
 }
else {
return [true];
}
return [true];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is when pressing the button catch click event and prevent the default action, then on your success condition, submit the form: Say

```
$('#yourButton').click(function(event)){
     event.preventDefault();
         //$.ajax({
             beforeSubmit: function (postdata, formid){
                var myGrid = $('#list'),
                selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
                IsIssued = myGrid.jqGrid('getCell', selRowId, 'Status');
                alert(IsIssued);
                if (IsIssued == true)
                    $('yourForm').submit();
                    return [false,"lll"];
                else
                   //Else you already prevented default action
                   return [true,"ll"];
           }
        //)};
     });
```

Comment: i am not sending any ajax request

Comment: then remove the ajax lines, and catch the rest of the event as described above! Do catch the click event only, it should work for you!

Comment: do add return false in action method of the form! plus don't use button type SUBMIT if you want to prevent the form being submitted, then catch the event.!